# Edifabric 8.1.4 not finding 835 spec

Tags: c#, edi, edifabric

I use Edifabric to read 835 files.
I am trying to update the edit fabric framework from 7.0.6 to 8.1.4

I had to update some of my code to work the new method signatures, namespaces, and property names.
It now reads the ISA and GS segments, However, it says it cannot find the given 835 specification file in the assembly.
The error message I get is:

“*Type with attribute'[Message(X12, 005010X221A1, 835)]' was not found in assembly 'XXXX.XX.Business, Version=2013.12.10.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.*”

The assembly name and the location of my 835 spec/rule files have not change.
When I opened the assembly in Dot Net Peek I see the specs.
Do I need to do something different in 8.1.4 for it find my spec files?

sample 1

[image]

sample 2
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message explains, your class needs to be attributed with [Message(X12, 005010X221A1, 835)] to be compatible with version 8.1.4. The latest specs contain only a C# file containing classes annotated with our custom attributes and aren't paired with XSD files anymore. This version of ediFabric does not rely on\use Xml serialization or Xsd validation at all.
For more information visit the resources section on [our website](http://www.edifabric.com).

Comment: Thanks, it look's like I need to add the attributes for the Groups, segments and property order as well.